# Связь базы данных и проекта C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Работаю с СУБД совсем недавно и сейчас возник такой вопрос:
Мне надо разработать программу с интерфейсом по работе с вполне фиксированной базой данных, по результату разработки мне нужно будет отправить результирующий проект на совершенно другой ПК (собственно для проверки). В пределах своего компьютера я подключил базу данных, но не имею понятия как правильно сделать так, чтобы при проверке человек получил доступ к этой же базе данных с уже заложенными в ней таблицами и данными.

[image: Связь]

Comment: Необходимо сгенерировать и передать скрипт создания и заполнения БД этому человеку либо использовать SQLite.

Comment: Если речь идет о mysql может проще создать (перенести) базу на каком-нибудь бесплатном или дешевом хостинге, а строку подключения прописать в коде или файле конфигурации проекта. В этом случае не нужно вообще задумываться о переносе БД и скриптах, приложение просто законектится с базой на удаленном сервере. Имейте ввиду, что на некоторых хостингах стоят фильтры по IP для внешних подключений к БД.

Comment: Если у Вас есть "белый" IP, то в принципе и без хостингов можно. Используемую Вами базу просто откройте на доступ этому человеку, а в приложении пропишите в конфигах или коде, как предложили выше, адрес для подключения.

Comment: Нет, проще хостинг. Во-первых, "если" белый IP, во-вторых сложно на внешку открывать доступ, с файерволами, настройками роутеров возиться и прочей конфигурацией, на хостинге уже все настроено, только IP-адреса добавить

Comment: Возможно. Тут уже дело вкуса. Кроме того, ему все равно тогда нужен скрипт, что бы перенести данные на хостинг. Где-нибудь все равно возится придется.

Comment: Используй SQLite + https://github.com/msallin/SQLiteCodeFirst для удобства

Comment: У вас точно MySQL? Судя по dbo на скриншоте - у вас MS SQL Server. Как именно у вас подключена база в пределах вашего компьютера. Какой именно connection string прописан? Как именно работаете с базой из кода? Через EF? Вручную? Как создавали структуру данных (Code First, Database First?)